# Complicated query - few tables with grouped columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables:

```
Worker (ID, Name)

Box (ID, Name, ID_Worker)

BoxColor (ID, Name)
BoxSize (ID, Name)

Item(ID, ID_box, ID_BoxColor, ID_BoxSize)
```

So we have workers who create items and place them inside their boxes.
For sake of my secret work I changed topic and from my secret one to ehm boxes ;)

I am trying to create raport that have columns:

```
Worker.Name | BoxSize.Name | BoxColor(id=0) | BoxColor(id=1) | BoxColor(id=2)
```

Table Box is used in other raports so this structure of tables can'e change.

What I for example want to get is:

grouped Worker Names and for each BoxSize, to have in columns every Colour count.
For example:

```
John | X   | 2 | 4 | 0 |
John | XL  | 5 | 1 | 0 |
John | XXL | 2 | 0 | 0 |
John | S   | 3 | 1 | 0 |
Adam | X   | 5 | 4 | 0 |
Adam | XL  | 1 | 3 | 0 |
Adam | S   | 0 | 1 | 0 |
....
```

BoxColor is a table with not so many colors so its possible to hard code it with different sub selects like

```
(select count(*) from BoxColor where ID = 0)
(select count(*) from BoxColor where ID = 1)
(select count(*) from BoxColor where ID = 2)
```

I tried to do something like this but the query is looping ans it never stops "thinking"

```
select Worker.Name, BoxSize.Name,
 (select count(*) from BoxColor as BoxColor2, Box as Box2, Item as Item2 
   where Box2.ID_Worker = Worker.ID and 
         Item2.ID_Box = Box2.ID and
         Item2.ID_BoxColor = BoxColor2.ID) and
         BoxColor.ID = 0 ) as Red,
 (select count(*) from BoxColor as BoxColor2, Box as Box2, Item as Item2 
   where Box2.ID_Worker = Worker.ID and 
         Item2.ID_Box = Box2.ID and
         Item2.ID_BoxColor = BoxColor2.ID) and
         BoxColor.ID = 1 ) as Green,
 (select count(*) from BoxColor as BoxColor2, Box as Box2, Item as Item2 
   where Box2.ID_Worker = Worker.ID and 
         Item2.ID_Box = Box2.ID and
         Item2.ID_BoxColor = BoxColor2.ID) and
         BoxColor.ID = 2 ) as Blue,
from Worker, BoxSize, Box, Item
where 
    Item.ID_Worker = Worker.ID and
    Item.ID_Box = Box.ID
    Item.ID_BoxSize = BoxSize.ID
group by Worker.Name, BoxSize.Name
having Red > 0, Blue > 0, Green > 0
order by 1, 2
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the application level code/presentation layer if you have one (e.g. a simple PHP loop)

Comment: I can't do this cause in my web app I made flexible method of adding new reports. There are many others so I can't afford to create specific interface for just one report :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    Worker.Name,
    BoxSize.Name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN BoxColor.id=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BoxColor_0,
    SUM(CASE WHEN BoxColor.id=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BoxColor_1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN BoxColor.id=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BoxColor_2    
FROM
    Worker
    JOIN Box
        ON Worker.ID=Box.ID_Worker
    JOIN Item
        ON Item.ID_box=Box.ID
    JOIN BoxColor
        ON BoxColor.ID=Item.ID_BoxColor
    JOIN BoxSize
        ON BoxSize.ID=Item.ID_BoxSize
GROUP BY
    Worker.Name,
    BoxSize.Name
```